# Monitor displaying negative colours

Tags: lcd, monitor

I found an LCD monitor on a rainy day and I had to completely disassemble it in order to remove all the water. When I dried everything and reassembled it, its colors were inverted!

I wasn't really too careful, so maybe I did something wrong while reassembling it. But I'm curious, what kind of error could I have done for it to simply invert colours? Which part would even be able to do that and how?

Comment: If you flip a flat flex carrying LVDS over, and its pinout is symmentrical enough, you'll flip the polarity of all the bts. You really need to be a lot more careful when you take things apart if you're expecting to put them back together again.

Comment: @DaveTweed Yeah, the fault is all mine, should've had more patience. It's easy to think that you have everything under control after disassembling and reassembling so many things, this should teach me. But I don't think it was the FFC, the connectors were pretty fool-proof.

Answer (score 5):

One possible mistake would be to get one of the the (optical) polarizers backwards if it's not bonded to the LCD glass, the polarizers are usually done at 45 degrees so that the manufacturers can use the same polarizer on both sides of the glass.

So, swapping sides will turn the polarization angle by 90 degrees swapping white and black etc. getting you the photographic negative effect.

Comment: Ah, I think you may be right! The polarizing sheet was indeed not bonded. I will try that, thanks!